# Why does this Cosmos SQL query require a subquery?

Tags: subquery, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to understand why my query below will only work when using a subquery.

### Sample document structure:

```json
{
  "id": "78832-fsdfdf-3242",
  "type": "Specific",
  "title": "JavaScript vs TypeScript",
  "summary": "Explain the differences between JavaScript and TypeScript.",
  "products": [
    "javascript v6",
    "typescript v1",
    "node.js"
  ]
}
```

### Query requirements:

Find the `id` of all documents where the terms 'javascript' or 'csharp' or 'coding' are contained in either the `title`, `summary` or in one of the listed `products`.

To solve this, I'm using `CONTAINS()`. To avoid repeating the `CONTAINS()` for each combination of field and search term, I create a concatenation of the fields in question and name it `searchField`.

### Working query

This is the query I came up with. It's using a subquery `sub` to add the concatenated fields and products to the result set. Then, I can use `CONTAINS()` on `sub.searchField`.

```sql
SELECT sub.id
FROM
(
  SELECT
    o.id,
    o.type,
    CONCAT(o.title, " ", o.summary, " ", p) as searchField
  FROM o
  JOIN p in o.products
) sub
WHERE
sub.type = "Specific"
AND
(
  CONTAINS(sub.searchField, "javascript", true)
  OR CONTAINS(sub.searchField, "csharp", true)
  OR CONTAINS(sub.searchField, "coding", true) 
)
```

### Non-working query

Originally, I had the query written as seen below. I expected it to work as in other SQL dialects, but I cannot access `searchField` in the `WHERE` clause.

`"Error: Identifier 'searchField' could not be resolved."`

```sql
SELECT o.id, CONCAT(o.title, " ", o.summary, " ", p) as searchField
FROM o
WHERE
o.type = "Specific"
AND
(
  CONTAINS(searchField, "javascript", true)
  OR CONTAINS(searchField, "csharp", true)
  OR CONTAINS(searchField, "coding", true) 
)
```

### Questions

- Is there a better way to achieve the result needed? (Although, surprisingly, the query consumes only 230 RUs)
- Why is the subquery needed? I really want to understand this so I can learn when the use subqueries and potentially write queries that would otherwise not be possible.

Comment: You can't use a variable you define in your `SELECT` in your `WHERE` clause as it is evaluated before the `SELECT` and thus the variable `searchField` does not exist at that moment.